# Netgear Modem Power Supplies, do AMPS matter?

Tags: modem, power-supply-unit, netgear

i recently purchased a Netgear DGND3300 modem from USA for Australia.

Unfortunately it didn't come with a power adapter so i bought one locally, however the modem is recommended to have 12Volts and 1.5Amps from its power adapter, but my local netgear power adapter only provides 12Volts and 1.0amps.

is this bad?

The modem seems to work fine so far...but is it dangerous if i continue to use it like this, or is there really not that much difference that i dont need to worry?

any info would be appreciated. thx

Comment: You'll probably fry the power adapter in a short time (weeks or perhaps months). If you're lucky it will just stop working; otherwise it's possible bad things could happen.

Comment: @Chris S: I don't think that's the case. The OP's power supply is providing less power than the device actually requires, so burning it out isn't likely to happen. If the power supply were 12V @ 2Amps then there'd be a concern.

Comment: @Chris S: My bad. I thought you were insinuating that the modem would burn out, after re-reading your comment I see you were referring to the power supply. In that case I think you're right. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This REALLY isn't the kind of question we answer here normally - take a look at out FAQ, it explains how perhaps our sister site superuser.com may be more appropriate for this kind of thing in the future.

That said it does sound like you need a PSU capable of having 1.5A drawn from it, I wouldn't try it with the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

Your modem may put a strain on the power supply shortening its life. It could also lead to damage of the modem. You should get a power supply that supplies at least the listed amperage.

You should be able to buy an aftermarket power supply with the correct voltage, polarity and plug type and having a large enough output rating.